# Find the equation of the line tangent to

Tags: polynomials, derivatives

Find the equation of the line tangent to $f(x) = 3x^2 - 2x - 1$ at the point where $x = 2.$

For the above function, what does the derivative at $x = 2$ tell you about the direction at that point? is it increasing, decreasing, or neither? Why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. People will respond more favorably to your questions if you tell us what you have done so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The point of tangency occurs at $(x_0, y_0) = (2, f(2))$, where $f(2) = 3(2)^2 - 2(2) - 1 = 7$. So you have a point $(x_0, y_0) = (2, 7)$ that lies on the tangent line.

Next, evaluate $f'(2)$ to determine the slope of the tangent line. First find $f'(x)$ then evaluate $f'(2) = m$:

$$f'(x)=6x-2,\implies f'(2)=6 \cdot2 - 2 = 10 \tag{slope m = 10}$$

Then use the point-slope form to write the equation of the desired line.

$$(y - y_0) = m(x - x_0)\tag{point-slope form of line}$$

$$\begin{align} (y - 7) & = 10(x - 2)\tag{$(x_0, y_0)= (2, 7), m = 10$}\\ \\  y - 7 & = 10x -20 \\ \\  y & = 10x - 13\tag{equation of tangent line}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing the [maxima/minima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) with tangency

For  [tangency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Equations),

we have $f'(x)=6x-2,\implies f'(2)=6\cdot2-2=10$

So, the equation of the tangent is  $$\frac{y-f(2)}{x-2}=10$$

For the extreme values see Second derivative test [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test) or [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html)